# WKWebView on Yosemite not rendering correctly

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite, wkwebview

Here's how the two buttons on `http://google.com` look using Safari 8.0.2 on Yosemite 10.10.1 (this is expected behavior):

[image: safari]

Here's the same portion of the website rendered inside a WKWebView using Xcode 6.1.1 and Xcode 6.2 (6C95a) (this is **not** expected behavior):

[image: wkwebview]

Some other examples of WKWebView rendering with weird artifacts:

- [Google](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/2p3Q0O0C0r2w3h1O1A34/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-14%20at%204.36.45%20PM.png) - Buttons and top right corner.
- [Wikipedia](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/311L0R1d2O1r2t3r213E/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-14%20at%204.39.33%20PM.png) - checkboxes near dollar amounts.
- [Reddit](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0t3g3L343Y0d443z1h12/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-14%20at%204.42.44%20PM.png) - Top left logo and up/down arrows.

Here's the code I added on top of an empty `Cocoa Application`:

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebView* webView;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    self.webView = [[WKWebView alloc] init];
    self.view = self.webView;    
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    NSURLRequest* req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:req];
}
```

It seems to happen when using `background-image` (CSS). For example Reddit's logo via web inspector shows: `background-image: url(sprite-reddit.JqPSSyjOUZE.png);`. Maybe because that's a sprite, here a link to [sprite-reddit.JqPSSyjOUZE.png](https://www.redditstatic.com/sprite-reddit.JqPSSyjOUZE.png).

Comment: I don't get the visual artifacts (Safari 8.0 Yosemite 10.10.1) when I try but it does show an older looking version of Google for me too when loading through a WKWebView.

Comment: I also see an older version of Google when loading through WKWebView, [here's a screenshot of the whole window](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/2p3Q0O0C0r2w3h1O1A34/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-14%20at%204.36.45%20PM.png). It's not just Google, [here's a screenshot of Wikipedia](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/311L0R1d2O1r2t3r213E/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-14%20at%204.39.33%20PM.png). There are artifacts around the checkboxes next to the dollar amounts (e.g. $3, $5).

Comment: One more example, here's [a screenshot of Reddit via WKWebView](https://s3.amazonaws.com/f.cl.ly/items/0t3g3L343Y0d443z1h12/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-14%20at%204.42.44%20PM.png). Notice the artifacts in the logo (top left) and up/down arrows.

Comment: I'm getting the same corrupted images through WKWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this - when initializing your `WKWebView`, you need to initialize it with the `frame` argument:

```
webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
```

This example simply sets it to the bounds of the existing window.